# jQuery scrollTop being buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sub navigation menu animate a fixed position change after a user has scrolled down 200 pixels from the top. It works but it's very buggy, like when the user scrolls back to the top it doesn't always return to the original position, etc. I'm not strong with javascript / jquery, but I thought this would be simple to do. What am I missing?

Here's my fidde:
http://jsfiddle.net/visevo/bx67Z/

and a code snippet:

```
(function() {
    console.log( "hello" );
    var target = $('#side-nav');
    var scrollDis = 200;
    var reset = 20;
    var speed = 500;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log( $(window).scrollTop() );
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > scrollDis ) {

            $(target).animate({
                top: reset + 'px'
            }, speed);
        } else {
            $(target).animate({
                top: scrollDis + 'px'
            }, speed);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Scrolltop is buggy in IE 7/8 :(

Comment: Where did the Bacon ipsum dolor come from? Is that your own thing?

Comment: Also, the reason it doesn't return to it's original position is that your css has the original top as 100px, but when you reset it, you are resetting it to 200px.

Comment: baconipsum.com - it's hilarious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bx67Z/3/

I just added `.stop()` in front of the `.animate()` , and it works a lot better already.

```
        $(target).stop().animate({
            top: reset + 'px'
        }, speed);
    } else {
        $(target).stop().animate({
            top: scrollDis + 'px'
        }, speed);
```

---

You can also use `.stop(true)`

http://jsfiddle.net/bx67Z/5/

```
        $(target).stop(true).animate({
            top: reset + 'px'
        }, speed);
    } else {
        $(target).stop(true).animate({
            top: scrollDis + 'px'
        }, speed);
```

---

You can also use `.stop(true, true)`

http://jsfiddle.net/bx67Z/4/

```
        $(target).stop(true, true).animate({
            top: reset + 'px'
        }, speed);
    } else {
        $(target).stop(true, true).animate({
            top: scrollDis + 'px'
        }, speed);
```

---

So the reason `.stop(true)` works so well, is that it clears the animation queue. The reason yours was being "buggy" is because on every scroll the animation queue was "bubbling up" , thus it took a long time for it to reach the point where it would scroll back to the original position.

For information about `.stop()` , see here http://api.jquery.com/stop

Comment: The stop(true, true) causes the animation to skip while scrolling quickly, at least on my OS (win8) with chrome or firefox. I think the .stop() without the parameters works the best

Comment: I ended up using .stop(true) because the second parameter is causing the animation to skip. Works flawlessly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about a little bit of css and jquery both ??

What I did is added transition to side-nav to animate it and rectified your js to just change it's css. You can set how fast it moves by changing the time in transition.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bx67Z/2/)**

```
#side-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

(function () {
    var target = $('#side-nav');
    var scrollDis = 100;
    var reset = 20;
    var speed = 500;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scrollDis) {

            target.css("top", reset);
        } else {
            target.css("top", scrollDis);
        }
    });
})();
```

**NOTE:** When you cache a jQuery object like this

```
var target = $("#side-nav");
```

You don't need to use $ again around the variable.

Comment: Combining jQuery and CSS in animations opens a vortex in the stack-space continuum and causes unnecessary communication between developers and designers. Such behavior is inherently dangerous and not recommended.

Comment: Really? Since when does designers can't handle jquery? Besides in my opinion, you should use css as much as you can.

Comment: That works, but Jeff Davis is correct, and it also leaves out IE <10, and I must support minimum of 8. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @Lokesh. No, not really! Communicating with designers is not *actually* a bad thing. Previous comment said firmly tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am commenting all over the place I should probably actually contribute an answer.

The issue is that you are adding scroll events every time a scroll occurs, which is causing more scrolling to occur, which causes more scroll events, hence infinite loop. While cancelling previous events will fix the problem, it's cleaner to only fire the event when you pass the threshold, IE:

```
(function () {
    console.log("hello");
    var target = $('#side-nav');
    var scrollDis = 200;
    var reset = 20;
    var speed = 500;
    var passedPosition = false;
    var bolMoving = false;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (bolMoving) return; // Cancel double calls. 
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        if (($(window).scrollTop() > scrollDis) && !passedPosition) {
            bolMoving = true; // 
            $(target).animate({
                top: reset + 'px'
            }, speed, function() { bolMoving = false; passedPosition = true; });
        } else if (passedPosition && $(window).scrollTop() <= scrollDis) {
            bolMoving = true;
            $(target).animate({
                top: scrollDis + 'px'
            }, speed, function() { bolMoving = false; passedPosition = false; });
        }
    });
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bx67Z/12/